# Apache - virtual host - proxy - https

Tags: apache, https, proxy, virtualhost, transparentproxy

I have some servers with http apps. Now i need to secure it with https but i cant do it individualy, all of them is on same public IP.

So i decided to create HTTP Gateway - transparent proxy server. I must run it on Windows Server 2016.

I have installed XAMPP server and letsencrypt-simple. I have successfully requested and installed certificate, but on visit of website it is still make "**Too many redirects**" (and it is secured by HTTPS), whitout proxy it works well.

My virtualhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName [public_domain_name]
 ProxyPreserveHost On 
 DocumentRoot C:\HTTP\SERVER\htdocs\app1
 ProxyPass C:\HTTP\SERVER\htdocs\app1\.well-known !
 ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.9/app1/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.9/app1/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName [public_domain_name]
 ProxyPreserveHost On 
 DocumentRoot C:\HTTP\SERVER\htdocs\app1
 ProxyPass C:\HTTP\SERVER\htdocs\app1\.well-known !
 ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.9/app1/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.9/app1/

 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile "C:\ProgramData\win-acme\httpsacme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org\[public_domain_name]-crt.pem"
 SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\ProgramData\win-acme\httpsacme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org\[public_domain_name]-key.pem"
 SSLCertificateChainFile "C:\ProgramData\win-acme\httpsacme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org\ca-[public_domain_name]-crt.pem"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you test from command line, with `curl`: try to run `curl -v https://public_domain_name` and examine `Location` header in response.

Comment: thanks for directing on header read. After some research i found a solution. Alll problems is in loading modules in Apache. This article helps a lot: https://www.askapache.com/hosting/reverse-proxy-apache/

Comment: Thank you for directing me. Problem solved :).